# Paint Event Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, events, c++-cli

Currently I am working on a program on Visual Studio with the Windows Form Application, but every time I try to draw a shape or line with the paint event I get this error:

*C2228: left of '.DrawString' must have class/struct/union*

Below is my code that involves the pain event from the header file:

```
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
             this->Paint += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Paint);
     }
    {
     private: System::Void Form1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {   
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height);
     }
    };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're not calling `DrawString` in that snippet of code.

Comment: You'll need to learn proper C++/CLI syntax, it is not C#.  PaintEventArgs and Graphics are reference types, you use the -> arrow to refer to their members.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle( ...
```

to

```
e->Graphics->DrawRectangle( ...
```